# ShrinkWrap - Keep Original Edge Lengths

Tags: shrinkwrap

Is it possible to tell the shrinkwrap modifier to not shrink the lengths of certain edges? I'm having a bunching issue where it collapses the topology, if there was a 'keep original length' option I could apply to a vertex group, that would be amazing.

Comment: I don't think so, this would make the shrinkwrap algorithm much more complex... Perhaps if you rephrase your question to visualize your problem, we can suggest another technique instead.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I'm trying to apply a skin-tight uniform to multiple characters with different body types. I tried cloth and softbody, but they had other issues. I think the issue is my shrinkwrap mesh is too high poly, I will try low poly with mesh deform.